# How can I change devise alert message for password_confirmation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, alert

I am trying to change the alert message from the standard "doesn't match Password" to "The passwords do not match" but I can't figure out how to do it.  I've already tried adding the following to my devise.en.yml file:

```
activerecord:
    errors:  
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            password:  
              confirmation: "hey you billy"
              blank: "cannot be blank."
              invalid: "this password be invalid yo"
```

but this does not work.  The blank message works but confirmation does not.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting 'confirmation' on the 'password_confirmation' attribute instead;

```
activerecord:
    errors:  
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            password_confirmation:
              confirmation: "The passwords do not match"
```